# FFMPEG Bash Automation

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I have bunch of videos in different sub directories located in a directory , how can I run FFMPEG to convert all videos in those sub directory , and then put the output of each video back to the original sub directory that it came from.

```
for i in **/*.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -qscale 0 "$(basename "$i" .mp4)"/*.mp4  ; done
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to overwrite the originals? If not, please give the expected output filename for a video originally called `sub1/sub2/video.mp4`

Comment: i want to keep originals , i think the closest thing i got to what i need is using find                       find . -exec ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp4 \;

Comment: What was the answer to my question please?

Comment: well i wanna make different ffmpeg like 240p / 480p / 720p / 1080p ,

Comment: so i would go with the orginal file name then add to it the convert type so it would be video_240p.mp4

Comment: If you want to keep the original video, it follows that the newly created video must have a different name (or directory). So how do I deduce the new name for original video `sub1/sub2/video.mp4` please?

Answer (score 0):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean demonstration program may contain what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob

for mp4 in **/*.mp4; do
    new_mp4=${mp4%.mp4}_qscale_0.mp4
    ffmpeg -i "$mp4" -qscale 0 "$new_mp4"
done
```

- For each file with a path like `a/b/c.mp4` under the current directory it runs `ffmpeg` to produce the file `a/b/c_qscale_0.mp4`.  The original file is left untouched.
- `new_mp4=${mp4%.mp4}_qscale_0.mp4` removes `.mp4` from the end of the path in `$mp4`, appends `_qscale_0.mp4` to the result, and puts the final result in the `new_mp4` variable.  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of the `${var%pattern}` syntax.